# Speed issues using H2 database with OrmLite on Android

Tags: android, performance, h2, ormlite

i am coding an android app which needs a database. I won't use sqlite because i want a pure java core without any dependencies to androids library. To simplify the database access i'm using ORMLite.

So i've just compared the [ORMLite android examples](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/) 
HelloAndroid and HelloAndroidH2. 
I've reduced the functionality of both examples to read operations. 
The test tables(2 colums, primary_key;value) contains 2 datasets.

The Result:

- SQLite: results appears immediately
- H2: needs about two seconds to load results.

Where is the mistake or is it correct? Does h2 really need such a long time to load two *small* Datasets? Any other experiences?

Comment: Ahh sorry, opening and closing the connection needs such a long time! O_o
But else it's very fast!

Comment: May I ask _why_ you want no "dependencies to androids library"?  You're running on Android so that is quite impossible.

Comment: @Gray i want no dependencies because the project is a kind of library project which should support different surfaces (app, web, swing).

Comment: What I would do is create DAO classes for each of your platforms.  Then you can use your Android DAOs versus JDBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening an H2 database using the default options is relatively slow on Android, [as documented](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android). There are a few ways to improve that, most of them are [documented in the Android section of H2](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android):

- FILE_LOCK=FS (to use native file locking; saves at least 20 ms)
- PAGE_SIZE=1024 (using a smaller page size seems to improve performance here)
- CACHE_SIZE=8192 (to avoid using too much heap memory for the cache)

Also quite important is using an empty user name and password. If you don't, then the password is hashed, which is relatively slow on Android.

But in any case I think you will not be able to get the same opening speed as SQLite in the near future, sorry.